# Error connecting Tsheets api to Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When running the script below from the GAS environment, I get the error message: "Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Host"

```js
function fetch() {var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer "+token,
      "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.20.1",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Postman-Token": postman_token,
      "Host": "rest.tsheets.com",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }
  var now = new Date();
  var day = now.getDate()>9? now.getDate():'0'+now.getDate();
  var date = now.getFullYear()+'-'+now.getMonth()+'-'+day;
  
  var url = organization+'/timesheets?start_date='+date;
  Logger.log(url);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,settings);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

The original code was generated using Postman and works with no issues but I translated it from AJAX syntax to GAS and it doesn't work from the GAS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `Host` from the header fields, it gets specified automatically and fetch from Apps Script won't allow you to specify it, just delete it, because it is what is rising the error.

**About the rest:**

`Postman-token` is useless here, you can delete it also.
Same with `user-agent`, I believe it will be overwritten, so it can be safely ignored.

Finally, parameters as `crossDomain` and `async` although they won't rise any exception, they are also ignored, so you can just suppress them.

On [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) you'll find documentation about the allowed parameters for the `Class UrlFetchApp`, and on [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) you'll find the w3c documentation on the header field definitions.

This should do:

```js
var settings = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer "+token,
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
```

Comment: When I remove the header: host, the script returns DNS Error: any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: Check the url var, it's what it should be?

Comment: I think I found the answer. Our org's tsheets domain is not publicly accessible which means google can't send a request from its servers. I believe there's a feature to disable that security setting but I'll have to look into it. Thanks